# UI Automator viewer error : Error taking device screenshot: EOF Error taking device screenshot: EOF

Tags: automation, appium, ui-automation, appium-android, android-uiautomator

I am getting error while taking device screenshot from UI Automator viewer.

"Error taking device screenshot: EOF" error is getting display

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNPkc.png)

Comment: welcome to SO, please read [MCVE] , and provide full context to question, like what have you tried, any code samples , steps to reproduce, what steps you followed

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all try shuting down the [Appium Server](https://github.com/appium/appium) or [Appium Desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop) as they might share the same [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) connection and cause malfunction of the software which relies on the connection. When you finish taking screenshots or inspecting UI hierarchy - start Appium again.
2. Consider using alternative tool like

   - [Android Device Monitor](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor) (lives under `tools` folder of your Android SDK distribution)
   - [Layout Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector.html)
   - [Appium Studio](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/)